# New to this, help needed, this girl is lost!

Tags: usb

I bought a computer from someone and i thought it had windows 8 on it, instead it had Linux. I have no idea and really don't have the time to learn it right now. Can someone please tell me how to reinstall windows without a boot disk?

Comment: Can you pop into chat? Comments aren't good for long discussions... http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room

Comment: Basically, you'll have to download the ISO and burn it to a DVD and then install it. Also, if there isn't a product key sticker for Win8 on the computer, you'll have to buy a key which would cost about $110

Comment: 1 rep user cannot join chat, you have to talk to moderator and see if it's reasonable enough to create separate chatroom for this question

Comment: Just go to your local store, Walmart or Best Buy or whatever , and get installation disk. Yes, it costs money, because Windows is proprietary OS.

Answer (score 1):

If the computer still has a recovery partition, then you can boot from it by going into the BIOS and booting from that partition of the hard drive. It also depends if the manufacturer (like Toshiba) has hidden the partition, in which case, you will go to the BIOS options and should find a menu labeled "System Recovery". The only problem with either of these options is that whomever installed Linux on the computer may have deleted the system partition in which case you will have to purchase another copy of windows, or contact the manufacturer for a copy of the boot disks.

**Option A** - Manufacturer settings) Restart your computer and hit the appropriate F key (F2 or F8, sometimes Delete key) to enter BIOS settings. If the manufacturer included a System Recovery in the bios, you should see it and need only click the right arrow to move to that menu. Select the option to restore factory defaults and follow the on-screen instructions.

**Option B** - Boot manager) If you can't find the setting within the BIOS to restore factory default and there is in-fact a recovery partition still on the drive (and the boot menu does not let you select a partition) then you will need to download a boot manager and copy it to a CD or flash drive. [Plop Boot Manager](https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html) is a good one.

**WARNING! THIS WILL DELETE THE EXISTING INSTALLATION** Unless you select the option to save existing contents, these options will delete the existing linux installation. If this is not a problem for you, then continue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as installing an operating system without a boot disk.  You must have something to start the process, even if it is in a hidden partition on your hard drive, as mentioned before.

If the previous owner gave you the windows CDs, you can install from them.  If not, you can go to your favorite computer store and purchase your preferred windows version there, if they still have it in stock.  Since you are coming here for help, it is assumed you have Internet access, so you can purchase windows 10 from the microsoftstore.com, or an older version from some place like eBay.